# wrapping requests library request in Quart run_sync causes intermittent failures

Tags: python, python-asyncio, quart

I'm converting a Flask app to Quart and trying not to change too much, so for now I'm making requests on the server using the `requests` library, and just wrapping them in `run_sync`.
So I converted:

```
            response: Response = session.request(
                method,
                url,
                params=params,
                data=data,
                headers=headers,
                json=json,
                files=files,
                cookies=cookies,
                timeout=(connect_timeout, timeout),
            )
```

to

```
            response: Response = await run_sync(lambda: session.request(
                method,
                url,
                params=params,
                data=data,
                headers=headers,
                json=json,
                files=files,
                cookies=cookies,
                timeout=(connect_timeout, timeout),
            ))()
```

This all works fine except I've experienced a small but significant uptick in errors that I'm unable to reproduce locally.  I can't tell right now if the errors come from some kind of timeout or some other edge case when working with `requests` + async + Quart's `run_sync`.  If I use Quart, but just revert the `session.request(...)` to a synchronous call, the uptick in errors goes away.

I'm using gunicorn with `UvicornWorker` to run the app, using `uvloop` for the async framework.

It may line up with a `CancelledError` that I see in logs, but I'm not sure, and not sure why the `session.request` coroutine would be getting cancelled.

What might be causing this?

Comment: This is very interesting, but also very hard to investigate with the information given. Maybe you could try with debug logging and see if there are any more clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from other smaller issues, I realized what I was missing is documented [here](https://quart.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/how_to_guides/disconnections.html).
Quart throws a `CancelledError` whenever a client disconnects early.  For my particular application this happens fairly regularly and I was misunderstanding how that works.  An `await`ing task far down in the stack will throw a `CancelledError` when its distant parent signals cancellation.  So for example in a proxy application that waits for a call to a downstream, a `CancelledError` may often be raised when waiting for response headers from the downstream since that's where the bulk of the waiting time happens.  This doesn't have anything to do with the downstream request, it's just a signal that the upstream client to the server is no longer connected.

In my case I plan to handle these `CancelledError`s at the top of the application and send back simple http 408 responses.

This differs from Flask / other non-async frameworks.